# ¿Diferencias entre logger.info y logger.trace?

Tags: java, logger

Hay niveles en una instancia logger, quiero saber en qué ocasiones utilizar `logger.info()` y `logger.trace()`. Entiendo que `logger.error()` es para cuando el sistema arroja errores en su flujo, por lo general, en un bloque `catch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logger.trace()** es para mayor detalle que **Logger.debug()**.

Los niveles son:

1. ERROR: errores que surgen en el programa
2. WARNING: advertencias, como el sistema se esta volviendo lento, actividad sospechosa, me estoy quedando sin espacio de disco, etc..
3. INFO: datos informativos como cuando se inicia el programa, se procesaron los cierres del mes, etc..
4. DEBUG: información que es util para depurar
5. TRACE: información aún más detallada para realmente rastrear qué mismo pasó

El significado de cada uno es algo subjetivo. Pero podríamos imaginar que **TRACE** podría ser usado en algunas aplicaciones para totalmente reproducir lo que pasó en el sistema, con el tiempo. Como para hacer un replay. Pero en otras apps es solo una representación de pasos que se hicieron.

Todo esto te ayuda a depurar y monitorear el sistema desde lejos. Especialmente programas que corren 24hs en el servidor.

Esta es la documentación de Log4j sobre esto: https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html